# why is a database that no longer exists listed in master_files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

There is a database listed in `sys.master_files` that (I think) was deleted.

I cannot find it anywhere.  Does this indicate a possible issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its an issue but I just created and dropped a database and it was immediately removed from sys.master_files. Please look in sys.databases to see what the state column value is for that database. Could it be offline?

Comment: I have the same issue and the database in Master_Files is online, but is missing from sys.databases